# I am trying to create a calculator with javascript.

Tags: javascript, calculator

I can get the input from a user and i can put it all into a sum, but it retuns NaN.

my code:

```
var input1 = prompt("input 1","0");
var operation = prompt("operation","+");
var input2 = prompt("input 2","0");
var ans = (input1 + intput2);

if (operation = "+")
{
    document.write("input1 + intput 2 = " + ans);
}
else
{ 
    document.write("Other operations coming soon!");
}
```

Comment: You have typos in your code. There is no variable like `intput2`. Also, you assign value instead of comparison here: `operation = "+"`.

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of issues in this snippet.

1. You need to convert input1 & input2 if mathematical addition is expected. `+` sign before these variables are unary operator
2. There is a typo at `intput2`. In should me `input2`.
3. In the if  condition validate using `==` or `===`. `operation = "+"` is just assigning the value

```js
var input1 = prompt("input 1", "0");
var operation = prompt("operation", "+");
var input2 = prompt("input 2", "0");
var ans = (+input1 + +input2);

if (operation == "+") {
  document.write("input1 + intput 2 = " + ans);
} else {
  document.write("Other operations coming soon!");
}
```

Comment: I feel this is the most complete answer yet. It would be worth mentioning that `unary +` is used to cast the string to a number and without that, it's just string concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

Prompt return the string so you need to convert the string to number using [`parseFloat()`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjMxfzBypTVAhXCK1AKHSA4BTUQFggsMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FparseFloat&usg=AFQjCNFGjOkpZ1cWnWNYHgjw0eQjZTiL0g) .And check the spell of `input2` in `var ans` .

```js
var input1 = prompt("input 1", "10");
var operation = prompt("operation", "+");
var input2 = prompt("input 2", "2");
var ans = parseFloat(input1) + parseFloat(input2);

if (operation = "+") {
  document.write("input1 + intput 2 = " + ans);
} else {
  document.write("Other operations coming soon!");
}
```